# Get the AccessToken of Keycloak in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

i used Keycloak for the authorization management in my spring boot application, i get the access token from this curl command:

```
curl \
 -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
 -d "username=user" \
 -d "password=password" \
 -d "grant_type=password" \
 "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

now i want to get this accessToken in my controller, i tried this [example](https://www.n-k.de/2016/05/how-to-get-accesstoken-from-keycloak-springboot-javaee.html)  but it doesn't seem to be working, It displays this error
:

```
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following code

```
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();        
        KeycloakPrincipal principal=(KeycloakPrincipal)token.getPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
        username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
        emailID = accessToken.getEmail();
        lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
        firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
        realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();            
        Access realmAccess = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
        roles = realmAccess.getRoles();
```

I am using ***2.4.0.Final***

This is along the same line as the example, you can share your piece to understand whats wrong with your bit

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried your code, it works fine, but i did not know how i can get the access_token and refresh_token (the realmAccess and roles return null)

Comment: You will not get the refresh token. That you get when you hit KC using the curl command. You actually get AT and RT. AT is used to authenticate the service which is what you are passing to your sping boot module to authenticate and RT is used to refresh the AT once its expired. Can you share the access token that is getting generated

Comment: i want get the AT for add it in the http header, for i can get it in my angular application

Comment: curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d 'username=ineat-user&password=123456&grant_type=password' \
    -d 'client_id=ineat-web' \
    -d 'client_secret=d6d2056b-fc87-414c-a235-1d5cb83dff11' \
    "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/ineat-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"

Comment: {
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICItbV9rWHpiQlRzSDBTWmk2cE1aQlljVHBDRU13YXJZNzFkNzdKc1I5VkpZIn0.eyJqdGkiOiIzY2JjOWU3Ny03MTY1LTQyZDQtOTU4My0xMTViMjc0NjI2OTkiLCJleHAiOjE1MTY4NzkyNDMsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTE2ODc4OTQzLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgxODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvaW5lYXQtcmVhbG0iLCJhdWQiOiJpbmVhdC13ZWIiLCJzdWIiOiIxMzU3ZDVkYy0zY2UyLTRjMTAtWIiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiIwNTYxZjk0OC0.........",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for ? You get the AT from the curl (hope keycloak is running at 8180 port) . Once you have the token you can pass it to the service and if you can get the AT as list above to pass it on to downstream services

Comment: @Anunay  and @ akanzari Please can you explain where i found refresh token in spring boot ?

Comment: Refresh token is not to be found in spring boot. But rather this lies with the caller. When this caller made a call to keycloak to get tokens he would have access and refresh token. With access token he called your spring boot app and got his work down. When caller needs to invoke the api again, he can check if the access token he has is valid. if not he will make use of refresh token and send a request to keycloak to refresh the token. Your spring boot app will never refresh token. and api to refresh will be given by keycloak

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```
        <spring.version>2.6.7</spring.version>
```

Code:

```
    @Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,
        proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
    ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest request = servletRequestAttributes.getRequest();
    KeycloakAuthenticationToken userPrincipal = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
    SimpleKeycloakAccount userPrincipalDetails = (SimpleKeycloakAccount) userPrincipal.getDetails();
    return userPrincipalDetails
            .getKeycloakSecurityContext()
            .getToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to obtain the access token in your controller.

```
@GetMapping
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String getKeycloakAccessToken(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal) {
      return principal.getTokenValue();
        }
```