# Access Token keycloak inside spring boot controller

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I would like to know, if this is possible to implement the CURL command :

```
 -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
 -d "username=user1" \
 -d "password=test" \
 -d "grant_type=password" \
 "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token".
```

Inside of a spring boot controller ? Have you got any example ?

PS : I want to do that with REST Template but i don't know how exactly.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why curl command? In Spring there is `RestTemplate` or `Feign` for that kind of tasks.

Comment: @matejko Well, the question is that i want to know how to retrieve the token access from an application spring boot and not via postman or something else.

Comment: I think you have a similar problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432626/get-the-accesstoken-of-keycloak-in-spring-boot

Comment: Well i don't know how it works because i've made the same thing and i didn't get any result.